# Changing fill and stroke of svg object

Tags: css, svg

I've got an object that adds a svg image to my page but when I try to change the color of it, it's not working. It works fine when including the svg itself in the page but since it's 2300 rows long it's not a viable option.

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="assets/images/logos/brand-logo.svg" class="site-footer__lower__logo">Your browser does not support SVG</object>
```

The css:

```
.site-footer__lower__logo {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
 .site-footer__lower__logo {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
   -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
   -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
   transform: translateY(-50%);
   right: 0;
   margin-top: 0;
   fill: #eee;
   stroke: #ccc;
 }
}
```

Everywhere I read it says that this is the way to change the color of an SVG via an `object` tag. So how come it's not working?

Comment: Is this CSS inside the brand-logo.svg file? because CSS does not apply across document boundaries.

Comment: @RobertLongson No it's in my regular css file, but after it's included it's no longer across document boundaries since it's in the actual page? Or am I misunderstanding how it works?

Comment: html file = 1 document, svg file = 1 document. CSS only applies to the document it's in.

Comment: What Robert means is you have to have inline svg go use css on it.